# Por que algumas palavras têm múltiplos significados?

Tags: português-brasileiro, etimologia

Minha dúvida é relacionada a porque uma mesma palavra pode designar coisas completamente diferentes.

> Por exemplo:
>  
>   A palavra **manga** pode ser **manga de camisa** ou **manga a fruta**.

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Curioso também o nome da árvore, mangueira, que também é "um tubo flexível", mangueira.

Comment: Tentou procurar uma resposta? Aposto que [no dicionário](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/manga) tem a etimologia...

Comment: Por que não? Isso não acontece em todas as línguas? Me parece que a existência de [etimologia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etimologia) obriga esta possibilidade, quer dizer, quando as palavras podem evoluir, sempre podem surgir [homónimos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom%C3%B3nimo). Não entendo qual é a duvida aqui. Talvez seria pergunta para http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @DanGetz, talvez fosse, mas também se enquadra nessa comuinidade, não? Ainda que, no linguists a pergunta também deveria ser em inglês...

Comment: Há dois fenômenos diferentes: um, que é o que você menciona, quando duas palavras diferentes têm o mesmo som e grafia. Outro, quando uma mesma palavra desenvolve significados diferentes (como "remédio", que além do significado tradicional, também passou a significar "veneno", como em "remédio para baratas").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Esse é o tipo de pergunta que revela o quanto a linguagem é um objeto enigmático, que não se entrega facilmente ao entendimento. Essa é, aliás, uma das razões pelas quais *palavra* não é um termo tão simples de definir.

Pra começar, uma palavra não é uma unidade de significado, por incrível que pareça, mas uma unidade de *expressão*. Isso significa que, só de dizê-la, não se pode saber necessariamente o que quer dizer, e também que a mesma unidade de expressão pode facilmente assumir significados diferentes, dependendo do seu uso, ou seja, do contexto. Há, na verdade, uma infinidade de maneiras pelas quais a mesma expressão pode assumir conteúdos diferentes. A ideia de que há figuras de linguagem, como por exemplo a metáfora e a metonímia, é uma tentativa de explicar como isso acontece, mas a variação linguística é algo ainda um tanto misterioso.

O exemplo que você dá, entretanto, não é o da divergência do sentido, mas da convergência do significante, que é uma mera coincidência. Diga-se de passagem que essas coincidências não são necessariamente indesejáveis, elas estão entre os fenômenos que dão à língua a sua graça, a sua poesia.

Enfim, as suas duas "mangas" são palavras importadas de outras línguas, que eram diferentes, mas acabaram convergindo para o mesmo som e a mesma grafia. Nesse caso, o dicionário [explica](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=manga), pela via da etimologia.

Comment: +1 *Diga-se de passagem que essas coincidências não são necessariamente indesejáveis, elas estão entre os fenômenos que dão à língua a sua graça, a sua poesia.*

Comment: Sensacional essa explicação. (: